# Messaging Center Xamarin Forms Mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy aprendiendo a usar Messaging Center con Mvvm en Xamarin Forms , pero tengo un problema cada que ejecuto mi Command de OnSubscribeCommand, parece ejecutarse pero cuando cuando reviso mi ObservableCollection siempre esta vacio, alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

```
    public ICommand SubscribeCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> MessagingItems { get; set; }
     
    public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base(navigation)
    { 
        SubscribeCommand = new Command(OnSubscribeCommand);
        MessagingItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        SecondPageNavCommand = new Command(async () => await OnNavSegondPage());
    }

    
    private void OnSubscribeCommand()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainViewModel, DateTime>(this,"msn",(vm,dt)=>
        {
            MessagingItems.Add($"Message reviced at {dt}");
        });
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MessagingItems));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te muesto un ejemplo de como usar correctamente MessagingCenter en Xamarin:

Messaging Names

```
public class MessageNames
{
    public const string CuentaChangedMessage = "CuentaChanged";
}
```

ViewModel que activa el evento que actualizara la información:

```
public class RegistrarEgresoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Cuenta _cuenta;
    public Cuenta Cuenta
    {
        get => _cuenta;
        set => SetProperty(ref _cuenta, value);
    }

    private async void OnEliminarMovmiento(object obj)
    {
       //Send messages
       MessagingCenter.Send(this, MessageNames.CuentaChangedMessage, Cuenta);
    }
}
```

ViewModel donde se actualizara la información:

```
public class CuentaViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   private ObservableCollection<Cuenta> _cuentas;

    public ObservableCollection<Cuenta> Cuentas
    {
        get => _cuentas;
        set => SetProperty(ref _cuentas, value);
    }

    public CuentaViewModel()
    {
        //Cuenta
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RegistrarEgresoViewModel, Cuenta>
            (this, MessageNames.CuentaChangedMessage, OnCuentaEgresoUpdated);
    }
     
    private void OnCuentaEgresoUpdated(RegistrarEgresoViewModel sender, Cuenta cuenta)
    {
        ActualizarDatos();
    }

    private void ActualizarDatos()
    {
        Cuentas = new ObservableCollection<Cuenta>(_cuentaManager.ObtenerTodo.ToObservableCollection());
    }
}
```

Espero te sea útil, saludos!